# Flutter Material3 date picker has a bunch of extra top padding

Tags: flutter, date

My date picker in Flutter [has a ton of empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ7N2.png) right above the weekday "SMTWTFS" row that forces the date picker to be vertically scrollable. This seems like a bug, but I have no idea why this is happening. It doesn't seem like others encounter this issue: https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:640/format:webp/1*LKyNvPJKgQ6VsGXYn9Gyvg.png

When I tried searching for the cause in the widget inspector layout explorer, the extra seemed to be coming from a `SliverPadding` under the date picker `GridView` but the logic was pretty entangled and I couldn't figure out how to customize that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I realized this was happening because I'm using `showGeneralDialog` instead of `showDialog`. Switching to using `showDialog` fixes this bug

Answer (score 0):

I realized this was happening because I'm using `showGeneralDialog` instead of `showDialog`. Switching to using `showDialog` fixes this bug